# Using sinc function for interpolation of a dataset - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, interpolation

I want to use the sinc function to interpolate some data I already have sampled. I am not very familiar with Matlab, but I found the following script:

```
rng default

t = 1:10;
x = randn(size(t))';
ts = linspace(-5,15,600);
[Ts,T] = ndgrid(ts,t);
y = sinc(Ts - T)*x;

plot(t,x,'o',ts,y)
xlabel Time, ylabel Signal
legend('Sampled','Interpolated','Location','SouthWest')
legend boxoff
```

I understand how to change the formatting.
My question is, how can I do this for my own sampled data?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Edit: I tried replacing the x-values with my own multiple times, but each time it reverts to the original when I run the code. I'm not sure why this happens...

Comment: `t` and `x` are the input data. Replace those with your own sampled data. Not sure where the difficulty is. Could you clarify?

Comment: I replaced the x-values with my own data (same number of data values) but when I run the script it reverts the numbers back to the original ones. I'm not sure if this problem is something I have to change in the code or if it is something else.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to start with a programming course. You could for example read [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html). Then try to understand what each line of your script does. Once you understand the script, you will know how to modify it to replace the data in the script with your own.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.